# How robust is coxph when the proportional hazards assumption is violated?

Tags: cox-model, robust, proportional-hazards, nonparametric-regression

How robust is the coxph when I don’t have proportional hazards? How common is non prop hazards and how do I fix it? Does transforming variables help? Does non parametric  survival analysis handle non proportional hazards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How common is non prop hazards...

It's a given in any sample large enough, mainly because the diagnostics involve NHST and real live data don't follow probability models. Like detecting mean differences, we rarely care about just a p-value, but need to know the magnitude of effect.

> ...and how do I fix it?

4 popular approaches: fit the Cox model anyway with a robust standard error estimates, estimate restricted mean survival instead, or use a g-rho-gamma family, fit an accelerated failure time model.

> Does transforming variables help?

Not for any monotonic, increasing transformation because the risk sets and corresponding failure times maintain their intrinsic ordering. Non-monotonic transformations don't make sense.

> Does non parametric survival analysis handle non proportional hazards?

If you mean the log-rank test, that test is intrinsically related to the Cox model: the log rank p-value is the score test for the partial likelihood, so it's not a remedy for the problem.